# Sonata sonata_type_model_list show object name

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I tried to following this tutorial: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html#advanced-usage-many-to-one to create many-to-one form field.

But after the object is selected, i got strange selected value like in the screenshot below.

[image]

The entity StyleCategory had property `name`, i want it showed there instead the FQCN.
How to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your StyleCategory entity add method :

```
public function __toString(){
    return $this->name
}
```